# Given a table whose headers have backgrounds, can you CSS-rotate only the text in the headers?

Tags: css, html-table

Here's a JSFiddle that has [a simple table](http://jsfiddle.net/ou7qLcz8/) from an internal CMS:

```
<table class="rotated-text">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>property</th>
      <th>San Francisco, CA</th>
      <th>New York, NY</th>
      <th>Washington, DC</th>
      <th>Charlottesville, VA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>days of sunshine</td>
      <td>260</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>210</td>
      <td>220</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to rotate the text in all but the first  element by 45 degrees counterclockwise, but without also bringing along the background. I'm also hoping I can do this without changing the HTML -- only applying CSS. The result should look similar to this:

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm confused.  This is doable in css without changing the html as long as you rotate the `th` element, but for some reason you specify that you would not like to rotate the background on the `th` element.  In your image, it doesn't seem like there is a non-rotated background.  Is it imperative that the background is not rotated?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ou7qLcz8/1/)? It has the background on the tr rather than the ths.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah my fiddle does look very, ehm, unprofessional if you apply the background to the ths.

Comment: The title + description + image doesn't quite match, but see the following 2 answers posted so far, if any of them is closer to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could come was to dispense with the borders and the border-spacing in the table. Giving the borders the style you need may be unattainable. The lines between the `th`s I simulated with an underline.

```css
.rotated-text {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.rotated-text thead > tr {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.rotated-text th {
  height: 9em;
  max-width: 3em;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1.5em) translateY(2.5em);
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.rotated-text th:first-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.rotated-text td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="rotated-text">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>property</th>
      <th>San Francisco, CA</th>
      <th>New York, NY</th>
      <th>Washington, DC</th>
      <th>Charlottesville, VA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>days of sunshine</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So it's not perfect, and if other people could improve on this, I'd be interested in that solution too!

Answer (score 2):

How about this. Needed some additional wrapper elements. Add your background image to your `<th>`.

```css
.rotated-text {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.rotated-text td {
    text-align:right;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.rotated-text tbody tr > :first-child  {
    border-top:none;
    border-left:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.rotated-text th {
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b1/Portrait_placeholder.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.rotated-text th > div {
  transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
  width: 35px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.rotated-text th > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="rotated-text">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th><div><span>property</span></div></th>
      <th><div><span>San Francisco, CA</span></div></th>
      <th><div><span>New York, NY</span></div></th>
      <th><div><span>Washington, DC</span></div></th>
      <th><div><span>Charlottesville, VA</span></div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>days of sunshine</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here goes my try ...

Not sure about the background that you want to get... Is it the background of the th ?  Looks a little ugly .

The borders are real borders, but on a pseudo element of the first row of tds

```css
th:nth-child(n+2) {
    border-color: transparent;
    transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
}
.rotated-text {
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:first-child td:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    bottom: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0px;
}

tr:first-child td:nth-child(n+2):before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<table class="rotated-text">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>property</th>
      <th>San Francisco, CA</th>
      <th>New York, NY</th>
      <th>Washington, DC</th>
      <th>Charlottesville, VA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>days of sunshine</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>days of sunshine</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Clever! I think your approach is interesting.

Comment: Indeed. Applying @vals's `before` properties to my own solution would get you [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ou7qLcz8/6/), already very close to what you really want!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this the closest I can get. Using box shadow to draw the line for the th.

http://jsfiddle.net/vcbkport/

```css
table {
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 -2px grey;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>property</th>
      <th>San Francisco, CA</th>
      <th>New York, NY</th>
      <th>Washington, DC</th>
      <th>Charlottesville, VA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>days of sunshine</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```